# CraftCMS Documentation Site License

Tags: license

We stumbled upon the documentation site while looking at VuePress example sites. We couldn't find any license information on the documentation Github project page (https://github.com/craftcms/docs). We are wondering if we can use the site/theme for internal documentation? This will not be visible to the general public, only within our organization.

We also checked the knowledge base articles, issues browsed through the documentation site to find an answer but failed to find it. Please let us know if we are allowed to use the site/theme for our internal VuePress documentation site.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project at [craftcms/docs](https://github.com/craftcms/docs) includes a proprietary theme we’ve developed for our own internal use only. You’re welcome to use our [general-purpose theme](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/vuepress-theme-craftdocs) behind our class reference docs, however.

Comment: The second link is a 404 for me, is the repository private?

Comment: Even worse @MoritzLost, wrong link altogether. ‍♂️ Fixed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the theme link.